# date of birth and age in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two fields DOB,Age
for DOB: Date picker
for age: textbox

Whenever the date selected in DOB, it automatically calculates age.

My script:

```
$('#DOB').datepicker({
            language: 'es',
            todayBtn: 'linked',
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            onSelect: function (selectedDate,ev) {
                alert(selectedDate);
                var urls = "/Controllername/GetAge?date=" + selectedDate;
                $.ajax({ url: urls,
                    success: function (data) {
                       alert(data);
                    }
                 });
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            $(this).blur();
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
        }); ;
```

alert(selectedDate) is not firing.
the ajax call is not firing?

Comment: Have you initialized the datepicker in document.ready()???

Comment: I initialised in document.ready() only

Comment: urls means the path where my method presents

Comment: at first that alert box is not firing

Comment: it is working fine for me

Comment: @ Pragnesh Chauhan This code works for you..?alert box is firing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
 $('#DOB').datepicker({
        language: 'es',
        todayBtn: 'linked',
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        $(this).blur();
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        var dob = new Date(ev.date);
        var d = new Date();
        var age = d.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear();
     });
```

Comment: Thanks..!! from this i got an idea

Answer (score 1):

If you want find age  with js only in years

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MQpV4/)

```
function GetDateDiff(date1, date2) {
    return Math.floor(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / 365);
}
var d = new Date();
$('#DOB').datepicker({
    language: 'es',
    todayBtn: 'linked',
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    onSelect: function (selectedDate, ev) {
        var x = selectedDate.split('/');
        var dob = new Date(x[0] + ',' + x[1] + ',' + x[2]);
        alert(GetDateDiff(dob, d));
    }
});
```

Comment: In my application onselect function is not firing

Comment: @Kalyan remove `.on('changeDate', function (ev) {` part and run the again.

Comment: If I remove those line the datepicker is not hiding

Comment: Onselect function is not firing